# Can the Angular CLI be configured to generate Unit tests with a different extension?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-cli

I am currently working on an Angular 9 project which uses Angular CLI v9.1.3. By default the Angular CLI v9 (including lower and higher versions - as far as I know) is configured to generate unit test files with a `*.spec.ts` extension when issuing the `ng new` or `ng generate` command. Is there a way to configure Angular CLI to generate unit test files with a different extension - let's say - `*.test.ts` (or `*.unit.ts` or any other sensible file extension) when running commands like `ng generate component <component-name-here>`?

For instance, when running `ng generate component hero`, I would like the following files to be created (my project uses Scss):

```
/hero
├───hero.component.ts
├───hero.component.html
├───hero.component.scss
└───hero.component.test.ts  (Instead of 'hero.component.spec.ts')
```

**Background:** I am transitioning unit tests in my project from "Jasmine" to "Jest". In order to avoid lots of file renames, I had to leave the existing Jasmine unit tests in `*.spec.ts` files (until I can spare time to convert them into Jest tests). Meanwhile, I am writing Jest unit tests in `*.test.ts` files. Henceforth, any new component, service, pipe, etc which I create should be accompanied with a corresponding `*.test.ts` file for Jest unit tests. At the moment, I have been manually renaming the files from `*.spec.ts` to `*.test.ts`.

Comment: I suppose this is possible with custom Angular CLI schematics. Would be easier to batch rename old files any way.